# Getting an infinite loop when changing the state in useEffect

Tags: reactjs

So I have a base file, in which the default loading state is set to false

```
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
```

After that, I pass `setLoading` it into pagination component like this:

```
 <Pagination setLoading={setLoading} />
```

Inside the pagination component I have an useEffect that renders every time the page changes, which only happens on render and when I change the page. By default, it works, but when I try to `setLoading(true)` and once I get the data from axios `setLoading(false)`, It keeps on sending requests to axios and rapidly switching from loading spinner to the content that I get from back end. And if by default the state is set to true and I try to set it to false inside the `useEffect()`, it keeps on showing the loading spinner, without making requests.

Base file code:

```
import axios from 'axios';
import { useEffect, useState, Fragment } from 'react';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
import ProductCard from '../components/ProductCard';
import Pagination from '../components/Pagination';
import Select from 'react-select';
import { toast } from 'react-toastify';

const Store = () => {
  const router = useRouter();
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [products, setProducts] = useState(null);

  return (
    <div className='mx-auto max-w-7xl'>
      <h1 className='text-2xl text-white'>Store</h1>
      {loading ? (
        <svg
          role='status'
          className='w-8 h-8 mr-2 text-gray-200 animate-spin dark:text-gray-600 fill-blue-600'
          viewBox='0 0 100 101'
          fill='none'
          xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'
        >
          <path
            d='M100 50.5908C100 78.2051 77.6142 100.591 50 100.591C22.3858 100.591 0 78.2051 0 50.5908C0 22.9766 22.3858 0.59082 50 0.59082C77.6142 0.59082 100 22.9766 100 50.5908ZM9.08144 50.5908C9.08144 73.1895 27.4013 91.5094 50 91.5094C72.5987 91.5094 90.9186 73.1895 90.9186 50.5908C90.9186 27.9921 72.5987 9.67226 50 9.67226C27.4013 9.67226 9.08144 27.9921 9.08144 50.5908Z'
            fill='currentColor'
          />
          <path
            d='M93.9676 39.0409C96.393 38.4038 97.8624 35.9116 97.0079 33.5539C95.2932 28.8227 92.871 24.3692 89.8167 20.348C85.8452 15.1192 80.8826 10.7238 75.2124 7.41289C69.5422 4.10194 63.2754 1.94025 56.7698 1.05124C51.7666 0.367541 46.6976 0.446843 41.7345 1.27873C39.2613 1.69328 37.813 4.19778 38.4501 6.62326C39.0873 9.04874 41.5694 10.4717 44.0505 10.1071C47.8511 9.54855 51.7191 9.52689 55.5402 10.0491C60.8642 10.7766 65.9928 12.5457 70.6331 15.2552C75.2735 17.9648 79.3347 21.5619 82.5849 25.841C84.9175 28.9121 86.7997 32.2913 88.1811 35.8758C89.083 38.2158 91.5421 39.6781 93.9676 39.0409Z'
            fill='currentFill'
          />
        </svg>
      ) : (
        <>
          <div className='flex flex-row justify-center w-full mt-4 text-white'>
            <Pagination
              page={page}
              setPage={setPage}
              setSomeRandomState={setProducts}
              category={category}
              subcategory={subcategory}
              tags={tags}
              numberOfPages={numberOfPages}
              setNumberOfPages={setNumberOfPages}
              setLoading={setLoading}
            />
          </div>
        </>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Pagination component code:

```
import { Fragment, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { Pagination, PaginationItem } from '@material-ui/lab';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Link from 'next/link';
import axios from 'axios';

const Paginate = ({
  page,
  setPage,
  setSomeRandomState,
  category,
  subcategory,
  tags,
  numberOfPages,
  setNumberOfPages,
  setLoading,
}) => {
  useEffect(async () => {
    setLoading(true);  // <-- this is the place where the infinite loop is probably being made
    if (page) {
      const { data } = await axios.get(
        '/api/products/getProductsWithSearchParams',
        {
          params: {
            category: category && category.value,
            subcategory: subcategory && subcategory.value,
            tags,
            page,
          },
        }
      );
      setLoading(false);
      setSomeRandomState(data.data);
      setNumberOfPages(data.numberOfPages);
    }
    setLoading(false);
  }, [page]);
  return (
    <Pagination
      count={numberOfPages}
      type='page'
      page={Number(page) || 1}
      variant='outlined'
      classes={{ ul: classes.ul }}
      renderItem={(item) => (
        <Link
          href={`/store?page=${item.page}/category=${
            category && category.value
          }&subcategory=${
            (subcategory && subcategory.value) || 'none'
          }&tags=${tags}`}
        >
          <a>
            <PaginationItem
              {...item}
              // component={Link}
              // to={`/store?page=${item.page}`}
              onClick={() => setPage(item.page)}
              className='text-white'
            />
          </a>
        </Link>
      )}
    />
  );
};

export default Paginate;
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You are setting the states in the parent component and passing the `setState` functions as props to child component. So, when you change state, the parent component is re-rendered, the child component is re-rendered, and `useEffect()` is called again on each rendering.

Comment: @cheesyMan Thanks for the reply. I now understand, but how should I solve this problem? Is there any other way to solve it, other than moving the child to the parent component file?

Comment: As you're managing the state in the parent component, you should also run `useEffect()` (and call `setLoading`) there, passing to the child component only the result of the new state. Other option is to move the loading state management (so `useState()` for that particular state) to the child component, if you need it only there. Consider that there are also a lot of other state setting functions in your code that is not clear where are coming from(`setPage()`, `setSomeRandomState()`, `setNumberOfPages()`). Remember that each state change causes component re-rendering (and of its children)